# Strange CSS / z-index behaviour

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, z-index

I'm having a heck of a time working out why some elements on this page are 'punching through' layers above.

I've tried a range of tweaking using Developer Tools (positioning, floats, z-index, opacity, etc) and cannot work out what's causing this.

The minimal test case is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qae1wx0v/3/

And the specific issues are:

1. The dropdown menu to the right of the main heading is 'punching through' (sitting above) the main dropdown menu in the stacking order.
2. The breadcrumb separators (::after pseudo elements) are also seem to be sitting above the main dropdown menu in the stacking order.

You can see this by mousing over the main dropdown and noticing those elements further down the page appearing 'through' (i.e. sitting above) the main menu.

Any solutions that ensure the main dropdown nav appears above elements lower down the page is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:** The fix ended up being very simple (I was having dev tool issues)...

```
.sticky-container {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Thanks Ahmad Salameh!

**SEO keywords**
In case others are having similar issues, this relates to Zurb Foundation framework (which I hadn't mentioned before), Sticky elements, their Dropdown menus and the interplay between the stacking orders.

Comment: Actual code should be posted here, preferably as a snippet that actually demonstrates the problem. A link to your own site is probably not durable and may be worthless for future readers.

Comment: The link resolves to a login page, so your page isn't accessible. I agree with @Pointy - thumbs up : )

Comment: My apologies, can you try again? I'm not sure I can extract all the code and retain the issue. If you could take another look it would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If anyone is able to identify the issue here, I will commit to developing a minimal test case to add to this question so it's instructive for others in future.

Comment: I think the opposite should be done first, you create a minimal test case and then we help you identify the issue

Comment: Thanks for your convictions guys, I understand why you feel that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen your page and the problem is so easy to solve just for this div :

```
<div data-sticky-container="" class="sticky-container" style="height: 152.5px;">
```

Set the `z-index` to `1;`

I hope i understand you, If not please include your code above.

Comment: Thanks for trying Ahmad. Did you use Developer Tools and apply the fix on the page? It should work, but it doesn't :(

Comment: You are a legend! It wasn't working for me in Dev Tools. But it works when I add it into the CSS file. I feel quite silly for missing something so simple. Thanks again!

Comment: Working on a simple test case now to add to the question for posterity. It doesn't behave in quite the same complex way with Dev Tools, but close enough to illustrate your fix.

Comment: No, It's okay to miss, with the massive code you have.

Answer (score -1):

That is really easy to solve buddy, **do not EVER use pooptstrap**

Ok now, to fix all that disgusting and unnecessary nesting mess of html and css that poopstrap created, paste this code at the VERY BOTTOM of your HTML

```
<style media="screen">
  .sticky-container{
    z-index: 100;  }
    .is-dropdown-submenu-parent{
      z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Jean, I think your approach would also work. BTW Using Foundation framework, not Bootstrap. I used to only hand-code layouts from scratch. In the last couple of years I switched to Foundation and haven’t looked back. It’s only saved me about a million hours so far, so I’ll probably stick with it :)

Answer (score -2):

OK, shooting with my eyes closed here because I can't see anything (all I see is a login), but all my issues with z-index have come down to competing stacking contexts.

This is maybe best explained with a simple example. Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">
        <div class="grandchild-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
        <div class="grandchild-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, imagine you wanted the grandchild elements to be displayed one on top of the other.  If you give grandchild-1 a z-index of 10 and grandchild-2 and z-index of 11, grandchild-2 shows on top, right?

That's true, unless child-1 has a higher z-index than child-2.  If child-1's z-index is 10 and child-2's z-index is 9, all of child-2's elements will sit under child-1's.

This is because each time you assign an element a display value of either absolute or relative (regardless of whether you set a z-index), you essentially create *two* new stacking indexes; one for its children, and one for it and its siblings.  And all stacking indexes are calculated from the root of the DOM tree up (or the top down, depending on how your brain works).

Keep in mind that z-index has no effect without a display value of absolute or relative.